# Rails nested resource issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a couple of resources, a grant_application, and a household which are related with a has_one

```
class GrantApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :household, :dependent => :destroy 
end

class Household < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :grant_application
end
```

..and I also use the following route..

```
map.resources :grant_applications do |grant|
  grant.resource :household
end
```

However, I am having real problems when trying to create the form for /grant_applications/1/household/new

Using

```
<% form_for([:grant_application, @household]) do |f| %>
```

returns an error:

```
undefined method 'grant_households_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x23eda44>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% form_for(@household, :url => grant_application_household_path(@grant) ) do |f| %>
```